# I can't get the listView to show up when running the app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, uwp-xaml

I'm designing a really stupid app, but I need a listview to show me a list of different inputs. When I'm in the .xaml file designer, I can see the listview plain and clear, and added a listviewitem in it, but when I run the app, the listview doesn't show up.

I've tried changing the system theme on my pc, using the build tools tools when running to look at the "hitboxes" of my elements, and changed the border and background brush colors. Idk what else to do, or change.

this is the .xaml file for my app, without all the other elements -

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstListView" Margin="321,50,985,633" CanDragItems="True" RequestedTheme="Default" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
        <ListView.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ListView.BorderBrush>
        <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem"/>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*picture of it working in windowed mode*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE99K.png)

[*picture of the VS IDE I'm using*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB5dv.png)

Since I'm using Visual Studio as the IDE, I can edit the .xaml layout through a handy little GUI. When I click the listView element, there are lines running perpendicular from the middle of each side connecting to the border of the window(the GUI 'emulated' window layout I'm creating) that display the margin amount. On the intersection of the line and the border, there is a little chain link icon, and clicking that will 'unlink' the margin, and allow it to conform to whatever window size, and adjust to all the other margins. All I needed to do was 'unlink' the bottom and right margins, and it was working the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code to make a simple test. The issue is caused by the margin of the listview, the value for margin-right(985) is too big. You need to maximize the window of your app to see the listview. Another way is that you could change is into a smaller one.

Please refer to this document for more information about margin: [Margin and padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/alignment-margin-padding#margin-and-padding).

Comment: That works, but is there a way I can set the right and bottom margins to be automatic, instead of maintaining the margin that's too big?

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work without window resizing! Since I'm using visual studio(2019) as the ide, I can open the xaml file and edit the layout through there. when I click the listview element, there are 4 lines going from the middle of each side to the respective "window border". on the window border, there is a link icon, and clicking it will 'unlink' the margins from being statics, and I just kept the top and left. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could accept your reply as the answer.